# Change Database Source Depending on Login Credentials

Tags: c#, .net, database, web-config, inversion-of-control

I'm a new developer and I'm working on a project that utilizes the SalesForce REST API. A portion of my .Net project involves updating the web.config and the database depending on the login credentials.

For example, client 1 logins in, the  are updated with the correct Consumer Key and Client Secret. This client has access to Database1.

Client 2 logs in.  are updated appropriately. Now, the Database1 is switched out with Database2, programmatically.

Is there a way to programmatically change the database source depending on login?

---

Quick edit to my post. Client1 and Client2, in this instance, are two separate companies, that should not have access to each other's databases. I want to be able to utilize the same application for both clients, but update the web.config and the database used, depending on which company logs in.

Comment: Yo go on the wrong way, you don't change the web.config when different user logs in, you choose different values from your web.config depending on which user logs in.

Comment: you can still do this without having to use 2 different .config files.. logically if the logged in client name is `ClientXyz` then point them to first db entry if not then point them to the second..this is fairly simple to say the least

Comment: What are you using for data access?  LinqtoSql, Entity Framework, dynamic SQL or something else?

Comment: @JustinGould what does your comment have to do with the web.config or app.config file..? just curious

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using L2S or EF, you can create a class within your application that inherits your L2S/EF context class, then make the derived class's constructor do the work of figuring out what connection string to use based on log in and initialize itself.  You can then use that derived class as a data source as needed.

Basically, it sounds like you may have a situation where you don't want to be updating the web.config every time you add a new client/database.  You'll want to store a *template* for the connection string in web.config, but not the strings themselves.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to update your web.config with the database data depending on the login credentials. You can include all the connection strings that you want in your web.config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="database1" connectionString="..." />
    <add name="database2" connectionString="..." />
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

And then simply retrieve the value that you need when you handle the user login:

```
var connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["database1"];
```

or

```
var connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["database2"];
```

Answer (score 0):

just add 2 entries in the .config file like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
 <configuration>
   <connectionStrings>
      <add name="DbConn" connectionString="Data Source=someDataSrc;User Id=someuderId;Password=somePassWord;" />
      <add name="DbConn2" connectionString="Data Source=someDataSrc; User Id=someuderId; Password=somePassWord" />
   </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```